# C++, SDL2, OpenGL, FoxEngine - Медленное движение

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl2

```
#include <FOX/FOX.hpp>

fox::Window window;
fox::Desktop desktop;
fox::Keyboard keyboard;
fox::RectangleShape character;

void Character(){
    character.setSize(100, 100);
    character.setPosition(0, 0);
    character.setFillColor(250, 0, 0);
}

void CharacterMovement(){
    if(keyboard.isKeyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_D)){
        if(character.getPosition().x<=window.getSize().width-character.getSize().width)
            character.move(0.5, 0);
    }
    if(keyboard.isKeyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_A)){
        if(character.getPosition().x>=0)
            character.move(-0.5, 0);
    }
    if(keyboard.isKeyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_W)){
        if(character.getPosition().y>=0)
            character.move(0, -0.5);
    }
    if(keyboard.isKeyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_S)){
        if(character.getPosition().y<=window.getSize().height-character.getSize().height)
            character.move(0, 0.5);
    }
}

int main(){
    window.setSize(800, 800);
    window.setPosition(desktop.getSize().width/2-400,
                       desktop.getSize().height/2-400);
    window.setTitle("Game");
    window.enableGL();

    Character();

    while(window.isOpen()){
        window.pollEvents();

        if(keyboard.isKeyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE))
            window.close();

        CharacterMovement();

        window.clear();
        character.show();
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Создал движок ня языке SDL2 и OpenGL: https://github.com/RedBull4/FoxEngine

Написал код движения объекта, но почему-то объект двигаеться слишком медлено!

Что делать?

Comment: Для начала у вас отрисовка (да и вообще все) реализовано прямо в цикле обработки эвентов

Comment: А как должно быть по другому?

Comment: знаете как говорят: решение проблемы кроется в ней самой - главное осознать проблему. Если вы понимаете, что такая реализация плохая и чем она плоха, то решение очевидно

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch А точно? Ведь `window.pollEvents()` дергает `SDL_PollEvents` не один раз, а в цикле.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я вас не понял...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ну, вы говорите, что у него отрисовка сделана в цикле обработки евентов. Но похоже что нет.

Comment: По моему проблема в цикле "While", он слишком медленно работает!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat цикл while - по сути и есть циклом обработки эвентов

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Так у него вложенный цикл для эвентов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не понял, в приведенном коде только один цикл

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Второй спрятан в функцию `window.pollEvents()`.

Comment: Уже исправил, в движке была проблема!